# Notation in point set Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, notation

In $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R /\mathbb Q$, what do these ("$\setminus$","$/$") symbols between the sets of real and rational numbers mean?

Comment: Those are both versions of the "set difference", which is used probably determined by whichever notation is simpler to typeset.  A/B= A\B=  the set of all elements of A that are NOT in B.

Comment: @user247327 $A/B$ does *not* denote the set theoretic difference!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is [the set theoretic difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)), i.e. the set of all irrationals in this case.

While $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is [the quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group). It can also mean the result of collapsing a topological subspace to a point. Or [the orbit space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of $\mathbb{Q}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$ and potentially other things. So it depends on the context. Either way it is some form of [a quotient set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

**Edit:** As noted by @AlephNull, it can also stand for a field extension. In which case it doesn't arise from an equivalence relation, making the notion even more context sensitive.

Comment: Also $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ can denote $\mathbb{R}$ viewed as a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context:

$\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is the set difference 
between the reals and the rationals, so it equals the set of irrationals.

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ can mean the quotient of the group of reals by its subgroup of the rationals, (which also gives a topological group) *or* it can denote a quotient space of the reals where we identify the subset of rationals to a single point.